# How to download a audio file programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to download a audio file from the following link

[audio file link](http://in.orgware.in/Heather/Heather%20voice/phraseaudio1.mp3)

I have tried the other answers that are posted in this site. But I don't want to use ASIHTTPRequest so can anyone please tell me how to download that link content to my document directory.

Comment: `ASIHTPPRequest` is dead. Try using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) instead; it's amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could write something like this:

```
//Download data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<YOUR URL>];

//Find a cache directory. You could consider using documenets dir instead (depends on the data you are fetching)
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

//Save the data    
NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];
BOOL success = [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Don't forget to perform the operation in a background thread (using either libdispath or NSOperation).

Comment: @Buzzy: Sorry, i don't know how to perform this operation in background can you please help me or suggest any link to learn. Thank You

Comment: `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` is **wrong way** to download anything

Comment: @iMartin I tend to disagree. dataWithContentsOfURL is very convenient in some cases (doing testing for instance), and is very easy to wrap to perform async (using NSOperationQueue or similar) when things are working.

Comment: @Cipramill You are recommending synchronous solution that is “convenient in some cases” to someone, who don't know how to download file (no offense) and probably don't know how to move it to the background. You should recommend the _best possible_ solution that is applicable in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to download the file **to memory** and then write it to file.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL]
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                                              [data writeToFile:yourPath atomically:YES];
                                              // Audio file is ready to be played.
                                          }];
```

You could also create your own `NSOperationQueue` instance to perform writing in background.

If the file is large and you don't want to keep it whole in memory, you should use `AFNetworking` or you could also write your own implementation using `NSOutputStream` to write directly to disk.